# Angular 2 disable global styles inheritance in to child component

Tags: css, angular, shadow-dom

Is there a way to stop global styles to bleed in to child components without ViewEncapsulation.Native?

For example I have a global style
.container {
background: green
}

and a component

```
@Component({
  template: html,
  styleUrls: [url],
  selector: 'dynamic-lp',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
})
```

The component is a dynamically added component with variable styleUrls and template html, so I don't want to inherit the green background if the template has a .container class.

If I change ViewEncapsulation.Emulated to ViewEncapsulation.Native all works as expected, but I would like to know if there's another way to achieve what I want since Shadow Dom is not supported by most browsers yet

**UPDATE**

I've found a solution which is working for me. 
Wrap your sass imports in a "body:not(...)" assignment like this

```
body *:not(.innerhtml-container) {
  @import 'bootstrap';
  @import 'someother-plugin';

  /* Components */
  @import 'components/loading-bar';
  @import 'components/textfield';
}
```

And add a container class "innerhtml-container" around the component template.
For example:

```
<div class="innerhtml-container"><div class="container">...</div></div>
```

this way no css inheritance will be passed on to the child component